# looking for a clock widget that is unaffected by the mouse

Tags: software-recommendation, cairo-dock, screenlets, plasma, widgets

Between screenlets, cairo-dock widgets and plasma-widgets. One of them's gotta have this function;

A widget that hovers above everything on the desktop but is completely unaffected by the mouse.

I would use this by making a clock hover above everything and semi transparent. I also want to be able to click on windows underneath the clock.

After some experimentation, the screenlets widgets do not do what I am asking. I can make them float above everything on the screen but I am not able to click on windows underneath them. I need the widget to be COMPLETELY unaffected by the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish someone with plasma widget experience could tell me if this is possible for plasma widgets but for now I found a ... kind of hack/fix to get around the problem.

There is a screenlet called "digiclock"

If you run this screenlet,
turn off the gradient color,
make background completely transparent,
make the clock text semi transparent,

then the mouse will not be able to click on the widget... 
For some reason the mouse can not click on screenlets which use transparency , and it will be able to click on buttons from windows that fall behind the widget.

This is wonderful but sometimes/rarely, If the mouse catches a non-transparent pixel then it will not be able to click behind the widget... strange behaviour.